# On the Left-Hand Turn Constraint in Shortest Path Problem

Tags: python, shortest-path

I'm interested in automatically determining the quickest route from one point to another using data and algorithms. However, I'm not just looking for the shortest route, but specifically a route that involves moving always to the left. (Assuming Japan, where traffic moves on the left, it is believed that turning right is less safe than turning left.) Currently, I am using the Google Routes API to calculate routes, but I have found that with Google Routes API, the route does not always turn left (for example, there is an option called "side_of_road", and by setting it to True, the safety of the route improves, but it doesn't necessarily make it left-turning). Could you suggest what kind of technology or data I could use to solve this problem?

Comment: Look at the constructed graph and remove any edges that represent right-turns...?

Comment: Hi kfsky! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify what you mean by "moving always to the left"? For example, [this dog](https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/GettyImages-686763877-e1592410700684.jpg) is always moving to the left, but for no particular reason

Comment: it sounds like instead of always turning to the left, like you instead want to never turn right

Answer (score 0):

Not if it helps you but it sound like the shortest route problem in the [Open AI Taxi](https://www.gocoder.one/blog/rl-tutorial-with-openai-gym/) simulation.

You could train your own ai to solve your particular route problem.